# Using the index in a v-for to manipulate the :style

Tags: vue.js

I want to use the index value in a v-for to determine the `transform` property of an element, specifically `translateX`. However, I am getting the error

> 'v-bind' directives require an attribute value

Any help in how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div 
        v-for="(n, index) in depth"
        :key="index"
        :style="{ transform: 'translateX(' + determineIndentTransform(index)) + 'px)'}"
     >
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'ProductTableRow',
    props: {
        depth: Number,
    },
    methods: {
        determineIndentTransform: function(index) {
            return (this.depth * 2) * index
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You make a small typo, `determineIndentTransform(index))` should be `determineIndentTransform(index)`, this is making vue unable to parse you code, because a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Is the this-scope for that method correct? What happens if you write the function like so:

```
determineIndentTransform(index) {
    return (this.depth * 2) * index
},
```

Answer (score 0):

because 
    props: {
        depth: Number,
    } is Number type.so you should use it like so:

```
 <div 
    v-for="n in depth"
    :key="index"
    :style="{ transform: 'translateX(' + determineIndentTransform(n-1)) + 'px)'}"
 >
```

n = 1,2,3,4,5

Answer (score 0):

You are binding an object to `style`, that is why you are having that error.

try:

```html
:style="`transform: translateX(${determineIndentTransform(index)})px;`"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `determineIndentTransform` call has two closing brackets "))" instead of one. Also you should never use an array index as a key when using `v-for`. It defeats the purpose of the `key` property, and if your indices change, Vue won't detect it (since the index remains the same), which will lead to terrible side effects.